# Salesforce Profile/Custom Tab Metadata API

Tags: api, soap, metadata

i have been trying to push custom tab and data using soap/metadata api.
But couldnt change the permission set and field permissions.
URL:https://na35.salesforce.com
payload:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
 <soapenv:Header>
  <ns1:SessionHeader soapenv:mustUnderstand="0" xmlns:ns1="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
   <ns1:sessionId>******</ns1:sessionId>
  </ns1:SessionHeader>
 </soapenv:Header>
 <soapenv:Body>
  <create xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
     <metadata xsi:type="ns2:CustomField" xmlns:ns2="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <fullName>dummy__c.dummyfield1__c</fullName>
    <label>dummyfield1</label>
    <length>100</length>
    <type>Text</type>
   </metadata>
   <metadata xsi:type="ns2:CustomField" xmlns:ns2="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <fullName>dummy__c.dummyfield2__c</fullName>
    <label>dummyfield2</label>
    <length>100</length>
    <type>Text</type>
   </metadata>
  </create>
 </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 1):

Permissions are not stored with CustomTab, CustomField or any other Metadata type. These have separate metadata

- [Profile](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_profile.htm)
- [Permission Set](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_permissionset.htm)

It is not specified in components which Profile/Permission set will have what permission for components. Within Profile and Permission set CustomField information is stored under the ProfileFieldLevelSecurity (sub metadata tag) same applied to permission set.

> ProfileFieldLevelSecurity represents the field level security for
>   users assigned to a profile. In API version 30.0 and later,
>   permissions for required fields can’t be retrieved or deployed.

Comment: So, your suggesstion is, through API, permission set or custom field permissions cannot be changed. Is that so?

Comment: @MohanKrishnan No, Ashwani is saying that permission sets and custom field permissions are changed in different places. They can most certainly be changed if you use the correct metadata objects.